Failed connection to AD when configuring GCDS
I'm configuring Google Cloud Directory Sync for synchronising Google Workspace with Active Directory. When I set LDAP connection settings and test the connection, it returns this error:

Error: Connection failed
Exception: Network problem: Unable to connect to the specified LDAP server: simple bind failed: 127.0.0.1:3269, reason: SSLHandshakeException - PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIX$CertStoreTypeException: javax.naming.NamingException: [LDAP: error code 1 - 000004DC: LdapErr: DSID-0C090BA8, comment: In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection., data 0, v3839]; remaining name 'CN=(CA name),CN=(CA server name),CN=CDP,CN=Public Key Services,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=domain,DC=com'

I checked certificates on both the local server (DC) and the CA server and both are valid. Root certificate of the CA is also valid.

The message indicates that the GCDS java application does not trust your internal certificate authority. It could also mean that GCDS is unable to connect to the certificate revocation list distribution point (CDP).
GCDS must be configured to recognize your CA, and access the CRLs. Additionally, you need to configure an HTTP CRL.
https://support.google.com/a/answer/9746852?hl=en
